# What is the best way to loop through data C#

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I want to loop through some data on a device application. For example:

```
Select name, surname, mail_ad, phone_nr from cust_details
```

On the form I want to display row by row with next and previous button. For example:

**Name:**          Werner

**Surename:**      VDH

**Mail:**          werner@me.com

**Phone number:**  0716848805

**[Previous]**            **[Next]**

I've been having a lot of trouble with this. I have used List before but it doesnt work like i want it to work. Can someone please help me here.

How i've been using List:

```
public List<String> InfoList = new List<String>();
int i = 1;

conn.Open();
string query;
query = "Select name, surname, mail_ad, phone_nr from cust_details";
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
   this.InfoList.Add(dr["name"].ToString());
   this.InfoList.Add(dr["surname"].ToString());
   this.InfoList.Add(dr["mail_ad"].ToString());
   this.InfoList.Add(dr["phone_nr "].ToString());
}
dr.Close();
conn.Close();
```

and then in Next and previous buttons:

```
if (i + 1 < this.InfoList.Count)
   label1.Text = this.InfoList[++i];
if (i + 1 < this.InfoList.Count)
   label2.Text = this.InfoList[++i];
if (i + 1 < this.InfoList.Count)
   label3.Text = this.InfoList[++i];
if (i + 1 < this.InfoList.Count)
    label4.Text = this.InfoList[++i];


if (i - 1 < this.InfoList.Count)
   label1.Text = this.InfoList[--i];
if (i - 1 < this.InfoList.Count)
   label2.Text = this.InfoList[--i];
if (i - 1 < this.InfoList.Count)
   label3.Text = this.InfoList[--i];
if (i - 1 < this.InfoList.Count)
   label4.Text = this.InfoList[--i];
```

I'm using labels to display the data in. Problems I have:
Sometimes the order of the labels will get mixed up when I hit next.
or 1 label will not have any info in it.
when I hit previous and there is no more detail left I get exceptions.

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: you *should* exaplain what is your concern on List<T>, so we can offer alternatives (if need).

Comment: Post your sample code here.

Comment: Not enough information here. Try posting what you've tried, including any relevant code.

Comment: Please see my edit guys. tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what your looking for, but simply create a class and then use a `List<YourClass>`.
Define it by using `List<YourClass> myList = new List<YourClass>();`

To add values to the List you have to create an object of `YourClass` and define the values there:

```
YourClass myClassObject = new YourClass();

myClassObject.name = dr[i].toString(); //This is the database reader
```

`Class YourClass` contains the following properties:

```
string name, 
string surname, 
string mail_address, 
string phone_nr.
```

Properties are written like this and behave like global variables:

```
internal string mystring {get; set;}
```

Then you can loop through this list and use the variables with:

```
name_Lbl.Text = this.myList.name[i]; //This is an example.
```

Then use the OnPress-Event of the buttons to increment or decrement `i`.

Edit: Name your classes properly ;)

Edit 2: For more info about properties [CLICK ME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a class:

```
class CustDetails
public string Name
{
get;
set;
}
public string Surname
{
get;
set;
}
public string Email
{
get;
set;
}
public ulong PhoneNumber
{
get;
set;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1, encapsulate your details into a data bag class

```
public class CustDetails
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Surname {get; set;}
    public string MailAddress {get; set;]
    public string Phone {get; set;}
 }
```

Step 2. Create a list of CustDetails -- this is your InfoList

```
 public List<CustDetails> InfoList = new List <CustDetails>();
```

Step 3. Assign your queried details to your new class

```
conn.Open();
string query = "Select name, surname, mail_ad, phone_nr from cust_details";
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
   var details = new CustDetails { Name = dr["name"].ToString(),
                     Surname = dr["surname"].ToString(),
                     MailAddress = dr["mail_ad"].ToString(),
                     Phone = dr["phone"].ToString() }
   this.InfoList.Add(details);
}
dr.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Step 4. Keep track of your current position. Implement methods to access the previous or next details in your previous and next buttons. Your previous and next button handlers would look like this respectively:

```
//previous
if (current == 0)
    //you are at the beginning of the list, the button should be disabled, 
    // handle it accordingly. In this case I just terminate
    return;
current--;
var detail = InfoList[current];
label1.Text = detail.Name;
label2.Text = detail.Surname;
label3.Text = detail.MailAddress;
label4.Text = detail.Phone;


//next
if (current == (InfoList.Count -1))
    //you are at the endof the list, the button should be disabled, 
    // handle it accordingly. In this case I just terminate
    return;

current++;
var detail = InfoList[current];
label1.Text = detail.Name;
label2.Text = detail.Surname;
label3.Text = detail.MailAddress;
label4.Text = detail.Phone;
```

**Just make sure that you can keep track of "current" between method calls** Either add it as a parameter, or create a global variable.